# Django blog error

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to integrate this [Blog](https://github.com/eldarion/biblion).I have unpacked this in my site directory when i am restarting django. I get the error as no module named `creole`

`Does this blog work with python 2.4`

Comment: You'd think that a file called **requirements.txt** just *might* be worth taking a peek at...

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:I had  a look at it,but my question how to install creole module.Working on Python2.4 i do not have easy_install and pip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the requirements from [**`https://github.com/eldarion/biblion/blob/master/requirements.txt`**](https://github.com/eldarion/biblion/blob/master/requirements.txt)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the project or module in question, but I think it's just a matter of installing creole via a Python package manager. For example:

`easy_install creole`

`pip install creole`